# Keyboard Extension Not Working with iOS 8.1 Simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6.1-gm-seed

I just updated to Xcode 6.1 and my keyboard extension app, which was working fine with 6.0.x, is now  not selectable via the nextinputmode button. This works fine on the actual device but not on the simulator. I can add the keyboard in settings with no trouble. Anyone else have this problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Update:** This has been fixed in iOS 8.2 beta 2, according to release notes.

---

<s>From iOS 8.1 beta release notes:</s>

> Known Issue 3rd party keyboards may not appear in Safari, Maps or 3rd
>   party apps on the Simulator.
>
> Workaround: Keyboards should be testable in Calendar, Spotlight,
>   Contacts, and Photos.

This is what you are seeing.

I guess they were so busy fixing other bugs in the developer tools, they just didn't have time to fix ridiculous new bugs they introduced in 8.1.

Open a bug report, and maybe it will be fixed in 8.2.

Comment: 'Maybe it will be fixed in 8.2'... Is that a flying pig I see over there?

Comment: @simonthumper Porco Dio!

Comment: This is not only an issue of keyboard extensions – keyboards are stuck to English and Emoji in all of my apps. I can't type Cyrillic anymore! This is much worse than it seems.

Comment: This is really annoying, can not test keyboards in its own container app. It worked just fine with iOS 8.0.2 just fine. 8.1 broke it terribly.